# Strange behaviour of a build in debug mode and an Adhoc build?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, debugging, adhoc

I am trying to implement a sample application that will be running in background. When a message is received, it will notify with a local notification. It will be a continuous process.

It's working fine when it is in debug mode. But when i am making an Adhoc build and sync it with my device it doesn't working continuously. It is just receiving the messages once.

I can't understand that why this is working when it is in debug mode but not working when it is an Adhoc build !!!!!!!

Please help me to get out of this. **ANY SUGGESTION WILL BE APPRECIATED.**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What device, platform, language?

Comment: Device is iPad 2 (iOS 5.0.1). Platform is Objective C and C++ both.